# UWP: Printing static content of a WebView results in blurry/fuzzy text

Tags: printing, webview, uwp

I have a basic UWP app that supports printing a document (text, no images). Internally I split the document into multiple pages. Each page is loaded as static HTML page into a `WebView` that I then use to print.

My problem is that printed text looks blurry/fuzzy. When I printed to a PDF and zoom into the page, I noticed that the text does not scale and cannot be selected. It looks as if my document was printed (i.e. exported) as image and not as text.

Here is an example at the actual size:

[image: actual size]

Note how even at the actual size, the text is blurry.

Now zoomed in:

[image: zoomed]

Here is is clearly visible that the text is not scaled as vector, but as image.

My question: how can I print the contents of a WebView in a UWP app and have the text scale correctly? Is there a way to configure the `WebView` or `PrintTask` to specify the quality?

For reference, the code to produce a single page:

```
private WebView makePage(int pageNumber, Size pageSize, double scaleFactor) {
    var webView = new WebView();

    webView.Width = pageSize.Width;
    webView.Height = pageSize.Height;

    webView.ScriptNotify += WebView_ScriptNotify;

    // Generate HTML and load into WebView, wait 
    // for scriptNotify...

    return webView;
}
```

Comment: Could you share a mini sample project  that could reproduce this issue, and I don't know how do you print the webview content?

Comment: Hi @NicoZhu-MSFT, I have the very same problem, and here is an MCVE to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/cghersi/UWPExamples/tree/master/WebViewPrint